# Spotify not playing next song, instead playing random song from playlist

Tags: spotify

When i try to play next song via my keyboard shortcut or with the arrows on spotify, it doesn't go to the next song, it just plays a random song from my playlist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have "shuffle" activated. Turn it off.
On some devices, you cannot turn off shuffle unless you are premium.